# Body background image disappears when zooming out

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have reduced my code the basic basics to make sure nothing else is causing the problem. When I zoom out on my website at a certain point my background image disappears. It's not a lifechanging problem but I am however very curious why this is happening as i havn't had this problem before and I don't think it's supposed to act this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Background image disappears.</title>
<link href="css/indexstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
body{padding:0px; margin:0px; background:url(../img/bg.jpg) repeat-x #cfcfcf;}
```

I must be doing something wrong right? :P
It works fine in my windows 8 Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Can you please check using <!DOCTYPE html> at the first line instead of you long first line.

Comment: it's not disappearing on chrome or firefix

Comment: @Imran
Sadly this didn't work..

Comment: @YazanWYusuf It is disappearing on my Firefox...? Not immediately, but definately when i Zoom out very far.

Comment: What are the height and width of your picture? mine are big(849x313) and maybe thats why I still see the picture

Comment: its a repeating image of 577x1...